# Setting offset for Day, then formatting back to string

Tags: javascript

I have a date like this as my input

```
"2014-03-30 12:03:00"
```

I'm assigning it to a variable in javascript like this:

```
var firstend = new Date("2014-03-30 12:03:00");
```

Now i'm adding some days to it:

```
firstend.setTime(firstend.getTime() +  (days / 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

from here, how can i format it back to "2014-03-30 12:03:00"  in javascript?

thanks

Comment: There's no built-in Javascript function for formatting times in arbitrary ways. Either construct the result by hand with lots of concatenations, or use the Moment.js library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to format it manually using various date methods:

`firstend.getYear()+'-'+firstend.getMonth()+'-'+firstend.getDate()+' '+firstend.getHours()+':'+firstend.getMinutes()+':'+firstend.getSeconds()`